# Disable Labels in Team City

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

My TeamCity(8.0) instance was previously configured to apply labels upon successful builds under version 8.0.x. I've since upgraded to 8.1.2 and removed the build feature for labeling.

TeamCity is still labeling my source code upon successful build.

The [documentation shows](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/VCS+Labeling) that the functionality around this was change from v8.0 to v8.1

I have no build features enabled for any of my configurations so I'm thinking perhaps the configuration for this has been orphaned from the UI.

**From v8.0**

```
<vcs-settings checkout-mode="ON_SERVER" labeling-type="NONE" labeling-pattern="build-%system.build.number%">
  <vcs-entry-ref root-id="BitBucket" set-label="false" />
</vcs-settings>
```

**From v8.1 (current)**

```
<vcs-settings>
  <vcs-entry-ref root-id="BitBucket" />
</vcs-settings>
```

Is there another way I can clear/disable the labeling feature (Db/Xml)?

---

**Workflow**

1. Pull Request Merged
2. > > master branch built
3. Feature branch closed
4. > > feature branch built [2266]
5. ?? tag getting added to feature branch somehow
6. > > feature branch built (again) [2267]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check in the "build features" section. This is normally in the build steps section and is listed below the build steps. Check if there is any labelling enabled there

Comment: I have no build features enabled for any of my configurations.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually in `Build Features` of your configuration. But if you sometimes, in case of SVN source control, this is in VCS Settings `Version Control Settings`. Click on on the VCS entry to edit it, make sure you have `advanced settings` visible and there you should see `Labeling settings` section.

[image: Labelling settings]

Comment: Right, this is where it used to be in 8.0...8.1 it was moved to Build Features. Also, I'm using Mercurial.

Comment: Ok, open the vcs configuration in edit mode, in right pane you will see history revision trail, something like (Last edited 3 months ago  by Dejan Dakić (view history)) click on Last edited and xml will popup, check there if labeling rules are present

Comment: Awesome, didn't realize there was an audit trail.  I found where I suspected there to be a problem, but the settings don't exist in my current VCS root config.  Updated question with details.

Comment: try recreating and reattaching vcs root config